# VLookup On Another Workbook

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

Trying to make a macro that will take an input (a 13 digit number) from cell A7, A8, A9 and so forth until a blank cell is reached, and run a vlookup with this against another workbook.

However, I'm just getting the *#N/A* error and I can't work out why.

My current code:

```
Sub getData()

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual

Dim wb As Workbook, src As Workbook
Dim srcRange As Range
Dim InputString
Dim OutputString
Dim i As Long

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set src = Workbooks.Open("D:\Files\test1.csv", True, True)
Set srcRange = src.Sheets(1).Range("A1:H1").End(xlDown)

i = 7

Do While wb.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1) <> ""

    InputString = wb.Worksheets("Sheet 1").Cells(i, 1)

    OutputString = Application.VLookup(InputString, srcRange, 3, False)

    wb.Worksheets("Sheet 1").Cells(i, 2) = OutputString

    i = i + 1

Loop


src.Close (False)

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic

End Sub
```

I think it is worth noting that the reference I'm looking up ("InputString") is defined as custom format #0 in the "src" file. I don't really know if this matters too much, it should still be an integer?

Additionally, the "OutputString" could be either numbers or text, which is why I've purposefully let it undefined. I have tried defining it as 'Variant', 'String', and 'Integer' but that's not really changed anything.

Thanks.

Comment: Your `VLookup` is trying to access column 3 of a range that you have set to be only one column wide.  Possibly change `"A1:A8"` to be `"A1:C8"`?

Comment: @YowE3K - sorry, that was error on my part when using my test spreadsheet. I've edited to correct. It does now set the initial range as the top row.

Comment: (a) I assume you have checked that the cells in column A of the active sheet are non-blank for at least the range you are trying to process on sheet "Sheet 1".  (E.g. if the active sheet didn't have anything in cell A7, the loop wouldn't process whatever was in cell A7 of "Sheet 1", which might leave the "#N/A" in cell B7 of "Sheet 1" from some previous run of the macro.)  (b) Have you stepped through the code to see what the value of `InputString` is being set to?  (c) Have you checked that the csv file contains the values you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `Set srcRange = src.Sheets(1).Range("A1:H1").End(xlDown)`

This will get you a range of one single cell, on column `A`, i.e. `A20`.
Doing a `VLookup` on a single cell is meaningless.

What you probably meant was this:

```
With Sheets(1)
    Set srcRange = .Range("A1:H" & .Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row)
End With
```

This will set to something like `A1:H20`.

Comment: Thank you! This exactly what I needed. I had kind of worked out that something wasn't right with the where I was looking (getting #N/A other than an error) but didn't know how to select the range correctly.

Answer (score 1):

First you should change your src range which is actually set to grab only the bottom row, not the range from top to bottom.  Try

```
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set src = Workbooks.Open(""D:\Files\test1.csv", True, True)
With src.Sheets(1)
    Set srcRange = .Range(.Range("A1"), .Range("H1").End(xlDown))
End With
```

Second, I don't believe the CSV file would support a 13 digit number except as text.  VLOOKUP is very sensitive about text vs general vs number so if the new src range doesn't help, try converting the inputstring using CStr() first.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, this is correct. I had kinda of worked out that the issue was with my range, cause it was #N/A rather than an actual VBA error, but didn't know how to select the range correctly.

I know all about vlookup and variable types... That's why I initially thought it was related to that. I'm hoping using a String will work.